# Bubbles getting shifted for WMS getMap if POST is used instead of GET, using gutter in both cases

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

Bubble positions are wrong in case of WMS POST request. For example, a bubble is getting shifted from 31.82, -96.84(lat-long) to 31.77, -96.77.
I am using openlayers 2.13.1.

The layer creation Code is:

```
   wms: {
      options: {
        gutter: 200,
        tileOptions: {maxGetUrlLength: 2048},
        ratio: 1,
        singleTile: true
      },..
```

I am using projection:"EPSG:3857". SingleTile and ratio options are not being used originally, but for experimental purpose, but irrespective of that results are same.

As per observation,

> 1. GET and POST requests(using cURL) for geo-server give same images.
> 2. If I don't use gutter, it gives correct result for POST (and GET also)
> 3. POST url contains BBOX info, I am not sure use of that but it is different that FORM > BBOX, in case of gutter. If no gutter is used then both are equal.
> 4. I just went through OpenLayers code. It seems while determining GET URL (which gets converted into POST FORM) gutter is used to adjust BBOX, it is not happening in IFrame, I guess.

Comment: Can you maybe explain with images what wrong poistions you are seeing?

Comment: For example, a bubble is getting shifted from 31.82, -96.84(lat-long) to 31.77, -96.77

Comment: It's still not clear what behaviour you are experiencing. What is a Bubble? Is it shifting, or the layer underneath it? How do you know the locations?

Comment: By a bubble, I mean one object, like a circle which represents some data regarding a position. I believe that, for a single tile option, entire image being in IFrame is getting wrongly positioned when gutter is specified. I know the location as we use openlayers.control.mouseposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to debug OpenLayers code. I found that for IFrame module, gutter is not being considered while positioning in GetImage function. This consideration happens in image module. I tried to use same code in IFrame > GetImage and it works fine. Not sure this is the only way to do it but I couldn't find any other.

I have done following changes in IFrame > getImage function :

```
      var gutter = this.layer.gutter;

     if(gutter > 0){

        var left = 0, top = 0,
          left = gutter / this.layer.tileSize.w * 100,
          top = gutter / this.layer.tileSize.h * 100;

        iframe.style.left = -left + "%";
        iframe.style.top = -top + "%";
        iframe.style.width = (2 * left + 100) + "%";
        iframe.style.height = (2 * top + 100) + "%";
      }
      else{
        //original code for assignments to width and ht, irrespective of gutter
        iframe.style.width    = "100%";
        iframe.style.height   = "100%";
      }
```